# How to list all files for specific commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

For particular commit, I want to see what files have been modified/added. Is there a git command which will list all files that have been modified/added for particular commit?

Comment: Does using diff-tree answers your question ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/444317/2823065

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all the files for a commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: Thanks Joe and Laurent BILLON!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
git diff {commit} {commit}^ --name-only
```

Comment: This looks more "gitish" than my answer ;)

Comment: Sure, maybe i've not been clearly enough with syntax, sorry; braces are only there to point that is a commit, for example if tour commit SHA truncated it's cf23df: **git diff cf23df cf23df^ --name-only**

Answer (score 0):

### Use git-whatchanged

See the *git-whatchanged(1)* man pages. For example:

```
$ git whatchanged --max-count=1 76ca0a8
commit 76ca0a8d36ad764cae050430c63b0cbc28e6493f
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 16 12:23:42 2013 -0400

    Add Ruby version and gemset files.

:000000 100644 0000000... eaec1d0... A  .ruby-gemset
:000000 100644 0000000... abf2cce... A  .ruby-version
```

The lines with colons at the bottom show files that are added, modified, deleted, or whatever. See also the `--name-only` flag defined in *git-log(1)* for a less verbose list of filenames related to the commit..

Comment: Please don't use git whatchanged: it isn't well documented for a reason,http://stackoverflow.com/a/18585297/6309