# Git whatchanged shows file which are not changed

Tags: git, jenkins

Recently I migrated from svn to git repo, Jenkins Build email after the git migration is too long somehow, and it seems including irrelevant items (not really changed, but somehow a lot of files are in the change list).

On investigating further I observe my git local  repo show the files which are unchanged by a user.

If I check the git global repo, it has the correct number of files changed.
However, on the local repo I observe it was showing all the files which are irrelevant for the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make sure on your local machine to type:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then try again and clone your repo.
See then if the number of changed file is still important: no more [automatic eol conversion on checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250133/6309) should help.

(Note: [since Git 1.8.5, Aug 2013, `git log` is preferred to `git whatchanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585297/6309))

Comment: one thing i forgot to mention that i use linux for build whereas certain people use windows if in that case also can i set core.autocrlf as false

Comment: @gowthamanivel Yes you can, yes you should. Always false. For files which need to be converted, use .gitattributes core.eol directive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309.