# What flags need to be set on `git log` to make it have similar output to `git whatchanged`?

Tags: git, git-log

Per: [Difference between git-log and git-whatchanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022722/difference-between-git-log-and-git-whatchanged)

> Encourage new users to use 'log' instead. These days, these commands are unified and just have different defaults.

I only recently discovered `git whatchanged` but found its output:

```
commit deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
Author: Egg Sample <mail@example.com>
Date: Mon Jan 28 16:32:04 2019 -0800

    change some files

:100777 100644 abaddad1 feeb1e42 M      src/changemymode.txt
:100644 100644 1234abcd abcd1234 M      src/changemycontent.txt
:000000 100755 00000000 6600abcd A      src/addme.txt
:100755 000000 feed1bee 00000000 D      src/deleteme.txt
```

useful for a particular workflow I had recently (involving a branch with many file mode changes). Out of curiosity, what would I need to do to make `git log` behave in such a manner, i.e.:

- show the commit information,
- the old mode, new mode, hashes, `Modified|Added|Deleted` and filenames of the files that changed
- and not the diffs themselves
- (and exclude merges by default, which is also called out as `git whatchanged` behavior).

I figured it might be something in the `--stat` or `--format` options, but `git log --help` doesn't seem to mention anything about getting the file modes and object hashes printed in conjunction with these options, and a quick scan of said document doesn't have anything jump out at me.

Comment: `git whatchanged` = `git log --raw` (well, and, according to the whatchanged page, `--no-merges` as well).

Comment: @torek Welp, that'll do it. Now I know that the format in question is "the summary of changes in raw diff format." Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this question is not left unanswered:

By this [revised answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585297/624066), newer versions of git explain this on `man git-whatchanged`

> The **whatchanged** command is essentially the same as **git-log**(1) but defaults to show the raw format diff output and to skip merges.

So:

```
git log --raw --no-merges
```