# What does this boolean "(number & 1) == 0" mean?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, boolean, int

[On CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/22750/4884) I posted a working piece of code and asked for tips to improve it. One I got was to use a boolean method to check if an ArrayList had an even number of indices (which was required). This was the code that was suggested:

```
private static boolean isEven(int number)
{
    return (number & 1) == 0;
}
```

As I've already pestered that particular user for a lot of help, I've decided it's time I pestered the SO community! I don't really understand how this works. The method is called and takes the size of the ArrayList as a parameter (i.e. ArrayList has ten elements, number = 10).

I know a single `&` runs the comparison of both number and 1, but I got lost after that.

The way I read it, it is saying return true if `number == 0` and `1 == 0`. I know the first isn't true and the latter obviously doesn't make sense. Could anybody help me out?

**Edit: I should probably add that the code does work, in case anyone is wondering.**

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: What's infuriating is that I studied this early on at university and had forgotten all about it. Seems so obvious now!

Comment: Anybody know who linked this to that other post (which has nothing to do with this stuff)? Can I remove it somehow?

Comment: Damn this is actually really smart!

Comment: it is faster then `number % 2`  to check if number is even by last bit

Comment: @cauon: My thoughts exactly. I could never have thought this up!

Comment: This was featured on Twitter.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: What do you mean?

Comment: @AndrewMartin https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/302768803719286785

Comment: You are misreading the expression. Take a look at where the parentheses are.

Comment: @EJP: Yeah, got it all sorted yesterday, thanks.

Comment: Although the code works, IMO, the fact that you had to post on SO asking about the code shows that the readability factor of it is lacking.  Probably would have made sense to use the modulus operator (%) in this case, although I could be missing something.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Could you please elaborate as to how is this faster than `number % 2 == 0` ??

Comment: @Vrushank read this [**bitwise operations are substantially faster than division, several times faster than multiplication**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Keep in mind that "&" is a bitwise operation.  You are probably aware of this, but it's not totally clear to me based on the way you posed the question.

That being said, the theoretical idea is that you have some int, which can be expressed in bits by some series of 1s and 0s.  For example:

```
...10110110
```

In binary, because it is base 2, whenever the bitwise version of the number ends in 0, it is even, and when it ends in 1 it is odd.

Therefore, doing a bitwise & with 1 for the above is:

```
...10110110 & ...00000001
```

Of course, this is 0, so you can say that the original input was even.

Alternatively, consider an odd number.  For example, add 1 to what we had above.  Then

```
...10110111 & ...00000001
```

Is equal to 1, and is therefore, not equal to zero.  Voila.

Comment: Thanks - your explanation makes it very clear. Plus any answer which ends in a Voila deserves an upvote.

Comment: Should probably also be aware of negative numbers in this answer.

Comment: Also, I'd possibly amend this answer to include the factoid that `n%k == n&(k-1)` for all `k` which are a positive power of 2. It might not be what the asker asked but it's a handy thing to know.

Comment: @fluffy not saying that it wouldn't work, but not everyone knows two's complement.

Comment: @fluffy shouldn't there be a `log` or `2^` somewhere in that expression?

Comment: Note that strictly speaking using binary operators like `&` on signed ints is implementation-defined (because it depends on the interal representation of signed ints, which is implementation-defined). In practice, all modern C implementations use two's complement, so the point is moot. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1161712/43681

Comment: @AlvinWong: For our assignment we are only dealing with positive numbers greater than 0. There are catches built into the runner main class to prevent any value less than or equal to 0 being accepted, so that's not an issue. Good point though!

Comment: @Navin Nope. You could also write it as `(n%pow(2,k))==n&(pow(2,k)-1)` or, a bit more efficiently, `n%(1<<k)`==n&((1<<k)-1)` but that's just a less-readable way of saying that the equivalence is for powers of 2.

Comment: @AlvinWong And why do they have to know 2's complement?

Answer (score 72):

You can determine the number either is even or odd by the *last bit* in its binary representation:

```
1 -> 00000000000000000000000000000001 (odd)
2 -> 00000000000000000000000000000010 (even)
3 -> 00000000000000000000000000000011 (odd)
4 -> 00000000000000000000000000000100 (even)
5 -> 00000000000000000000000000000101 (odd)
6 -> 00000000000000000000000000000110 (even)
7 -> 00000000000000000000000000000111 (odd)
8 -> 00000000000000000000000000001000 (even)
```

`&` between two integers is bitwise AND operator:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

So, if `(number & 1) == 0` is `true`, this means `number` is even.

---

Let's assume that `number == 6`, then:

```
6 -> 00000000000000000000000000000110 (even)

     &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

1 -> 00000000000000000000000000000001

-------------------------------------

0 -> 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

and when `number == 7`:

```
7 -> 00000000000000000000000000000111 (odd)

     &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

1 -> 00000000000000000000000000000001

-------------------------------------

1 -> 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Answer (score 18):

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. `&&` is the logical AND operator

In binary, if the digits bit is set (i.e one), the number is odd.

In binary, if the digits bit is zero , the number is even.

`(number & 1)`  is a *bitwise* AND test of the digits bit.

Another way to do this (and possibly less efficient but more understandable) is using the modulus operator `%`:

```
private static boolean isEven(int number)
{
    if (number < 0)
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    return (number % 2) == 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have understood that you see. Honestly, the things I learn daily about Java. Never would have gotten that without people pointing it out.

Comment: I tend to use this exclusively. Clarity over performance in most cases.

Comment: I can't imagine it would be THAT much slower, if at all. Anybody got any information on this?

Comment: given that any half decent peephole optimizing compiler will see the `%2` and translate to `&1` also unless this is a proven bottle neck the runtime differences will be negligible

Comment: `&` is also logical AND. `&&` short circuits while `&` does not.

Comment: `number % 2` is not the same as `number & 1` if `number` is negative.

Comment: if you are being passed a negative length, then you have bigger problems! ;)

Comment: I'm curious if the Java compiler optimizes this away. @AndrewMartin It would be a lot slower. For &, you just iterate each bit and compare. % has to do more complex division.

Comment: @RyanAmos "Iterate each bit?" Bitwise AND is a single operation in every CPU I've ever seen - it's among the easiest things to do in parallel.

Comment: @MitchWheat There is no reason to throw on the `number < 0` case - while an odd negative number mod 2 is -1, an even one mod 2 is still 0.

Comment: Why IllegalArgument on negative args? They may be even

Comment: I should have made clear that the method can ONLY accept positive numbers greater than 0 (there are catches for it in the runner class)

Comment: If this is less efficient you should buy a new processor that does proper optimisations: even if the Java JIT doesn’t optimise this, the processor *definitely* should.

Answer (score 9):

This expression means "the integer represents an even number".

Here is the reason why: the binary representation of decimal `1` is `00000000001`. All odd numbers end in a `1` in binary (this is easy to verify: suppose the number's binary representation does not end in `1`; then it's composed of non-zero powers of two, which is always an even number). When you do a binary `AND` with an odd number, the result is `1`; when you do a binary `AND` with an even number, the result is `0`.

This used to be the preferred method of deciding odd/even back at the time when optimizers were poor to nonexistent, and `%` operators required twenty times the number of cycles taken by an `&` operator. These days, if you do `number % 2 == 0`, the compiler is likely to generate code that executes as quickly as `(number & 1) == 0` does.

Answer (score 5):

Single `&` means bit-wise `and` operator **not** comparison

So this code checks if the first `bit` (least significant/most right) is set or not, which indicates if the number is `odd` or not; because all odd numbers will end with `1` in the least significant bit e.g. `xxxxxxx1`

Comment: Note that a single `&` can be used as a logical `and` if you want to keep side effects from expressions like `f(x) & g(x)`

Answer (score 4):

`&` is a bitwise `AND` operation.

For number = 8:

```
  1000
  0001
& ----
  0000
```

The result is that `(8 & 1) == 0`. This is the case for all even numbers, since they are multiples of 2 and the first binary digit from the right is always 0. 1 has a binary value of 1 with leading 0s, so when we `AND` it with an even number we're left with 0.

Answer (score 3):

The `&` operator in Java is the bitwise-and operator.  Basically, `(number & 1)` performs a bitwise-and between `number` and `1`.  The result is either 0 or 1, depending on whether it's even or odd.  Then the result is compared with 0 to determine if it's even.

Here's a [page describing bitwise operations](http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html).

Answer (score 3):

It is performing a binary and against 1, which returns 0 if the least significant bit is not set

for your example

00001010 (10)

00000001 (1)

===========

00000000 (0)

Answer (score 3):

This is Logical design concept bitwise & (AND)operater.

return ( 2 & 1 ); means- convert the value to bitwise numbers and comapre the (AND) feature and returns the value.

Prefer this link http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/java-bitwise-and.shtml