# Determine whether number is odd or even without using conditional code

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

How to find whether a number is odd or even, without using `if` condition or ternary operators in Java?

This question is given by my teacher. He also give me a hint that it is possible by using a bitwise operator.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher meant `without using if condition` and not `without using modulo operator`?

Comment: Yes, he said without using if-else conditon

Comment: Disclaimer: the ternary conditional operator "?:" IS a if-then-else

Comment: @ToniToniChopper Your comment made 3 answers invalid :)

Comment: Do you mean "odd or even", or "odd or even parity" ? They are two different things. Your title says "parity", but the question just says "odd or even".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if an integer is even or odd using bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700911/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd-using-bitwise-operators)

Comment: Be careful with the answers recommending `% 2`. It will give -1 for negative odd numbers. If you use that to index an array, or if you compare it to 1, you're in trouble. `& 1` doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are few ways to not use `if` and get behavior that will be same as if `if` was used, like ternary operator `condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse` or `switch/case`.

But to be tricky you can also use arrays and try to figure some *transformation* of our value to proper array index. In this case your code could look like

```
int number = 13;
String[] trick = { "even", "odd" };
System.out.println(number + " is " + trick[number % 2]);
```

output:

```
13 is odd
```

---

You can change `number % 2` with `number & 1` to use suggestion of your teacher. Explanation of how it works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923514/1393766).

Answer (score 10):

Consider a number's representation in binary format (E.g., 5 would be 0b101).
An odd number has a "1" as its singles digit, an even number had a zero there. So all you have to do is bitwise-and it with 1 to extract only that digit, and examine the result:

```
public static boolean isEven (int num) {
    return (num & 1) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Then `if(isEven(7)){}`  ??

Comment: this is ok. But the if construct is now just within the outer method which invokes this method. I had also suggested num & 1 so +1

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ 7 & 1 == 1 and 1 != 0 so it would correctly return false

Comment: @msam I'm talking about using the method :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ `println(isEven(7));` :)

Comment: @msam Ha ha. That's it. :) Home work done for today :D

Answer (score 6):

```
int isOdd = (number & 1);
```

`isOdd` will be `1` if number is odd, otherwise it will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this?

```
boolean isEven(int value) {
  return value % 2 == 0;
}

boolean isOdd(int value) {
  return value % 2 == 1;
}
```

Comment: and how would you check that return value?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw now `'Without using IF'`

```
boolean isEven(double num) { return (num % 2 == 0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every odd number have 1 at the end of its binary representation.

**Sample :**

```
public static boolean isEven(int num) {
    return (num & 1) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick wrapper over the already defined process...

```
public String OddEven(int n){
String oe[] = new String[]{"even","odd"};
        return oe[n & 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
( (x%2)==0 ? return "x is even" : return "x is odd");
```

One line code.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
System.out.println(new String[]{"even","odd"}[Math.abs(n%2)]);
```

Method 2:

```
System.out.println(new String[]{"odd","even"}[(n|1)-n]);
```

Method 1 differs from the accepted answer in the way that it accounts for  negative numbers as well, which are also considered for even/odd.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EvenOddExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("\nEnter any Number To check Even or Odd");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int no=sc.nextInt();
        int no1=no;
        while (no>1) 
        {   
            no=no-2;
        }       
        if(no==0)
        {
            System.out.println(no1 +" is evenNumber");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(no1 +" is odd Number");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: check when number is greater then 1    number = number -2;

Answer (score 0):

you can also use bitwise shift operators
(number >> 1)<<1 == number then even else odd

Answer (score -1):

```
# /* **this program find number is odd or even without using if-else,
## switch-case, neither any java library function...*/
##//find odd and even number without using any condition

  class OddEven {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       int number = 14;
       String[] trick = { "even", "odd" };
       System.out.println(number + " is " + trick[number % 2]);
     }
 }

  /**************OUTPUT*************
  // 14 is even
  // ...................
  //13 is odd
```