# What is the regex pattern for all the even numbers between 2-200?

Tags: regex

I have an input field where it will accept only numbers between 2-200 and it should be even numbers.I want the regular expression for all the even numbers between 2-200 please help.

Comment: There is a much better way than using regex.

Comment: What did you try? There are several SO answers on how to find even numbers. Did you search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine whether number is odd or even without using conditional code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705184/determine-whether-number-is-odd-or-even-without-using-conditional-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must do via regex then this will work:

```
^(?!.*?[13579]$)([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|200)$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mO2qI6

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not something design to find the number in a range, you should preferably use:

```
if( (2 <= number <= 200) && (number %2 ==0))
{
   // doyour stuff
}
```