# Can anyone help to explain this part of code?

Tags: java

```
while((number & 1) == 0) {
   number >>>= 1;
}
```

I don't quite understand the condition in while loop, and what does it represent '>>>='.

Comment: Take a look at duplicates at top of your question (you may need to refresh this page to see them). Also this may interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923514/1393766

Answer (score 2):

The condition in the `while` loop tests whether the lowest bit of `number` is zero.

The `>>>=` operator is a *compound assignment operator* (see the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)). The statement is the same as:

```
number = number >>> 1;
```

The `>>>` operator is a bit-wise right-shift with zero fill (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)). It differs from `>>` in that `>>` will fill with the sign bit, while `>>>` always fills with zero.

Note that the code fragment you posted will never terminate if `number` starts out as 0.