# Git - How to get the first commit sha1 on a given date

Tags: git

I want the first sha1 after 00:00:01 hours on a given date, or if there were no commits on that day: the newest commit number before 00:00:01 hours of that date.

I only want results that are on (merged into) the trunk aka master branch.

Answer (score 2):

`git rev-list -n1 --before="2014/2/27" master`

I found out about this command here: [How can I get the diff between all the commits that occurred between two dates with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161609/in-git-how-can-i-get-the-diff-between-all-the-commits-that-occured-between-two)

Turns out what I really wanted to see the diff between two dates and this command was a stepping stone on the way there, found my answer in the previous link.

Comment: For those who's too lazy to look up what `-n` means, use `-1`