# Get changed and new lines of code since a particular date in Git

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I'm looking for a way to find the actual lines of code added or changed since a date using `git diff` or another Git command. Is this possible?

Currently with `git diff` I'm just getting the list of commits since that day but I'd like to be able to extract the actual code changed or added.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1161609/520162

Comment: If you use multiple branches, do you need all changes on all branches, or just the one you are on now?

Answer (score 2):

Using GitHub, you can quickly compare the current state with another one, a few days ago, accessing this URL :

```
https://github.com/USER/REPO/compare/master@{1month}...master
```

Using git command, and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1161629/1238019), you can use :

```
git whatchanged --since="1 month ago" -p
```