# Get list of files committed on git branch in last month from remote

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a list of all files that have changed on a github repo in the last month for the master branch.  My local clone does not have logs going back that far, so when I run the following command:

```
git diff --stat @{1.month.ago}
```

...I get a warning message, and a fraction of the changes.  I also tried:

```
git diff --stat @{1.month.ago} origin
git diff --stat @{1.month.ago} origin/master
git diff --stat @{1.month.ago} origin master
```

...with the same result.

How to collect this list from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get a diff which does not depends on reflog is to do a diff between the right commit(s).

As explained in "[How can I get the diff between all the commits that occurred between two dates with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692666/6309)", in your case, the right commit is (using [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)):

```
git rev-list -n1 --first-parent --until=<a date string> <a ref>
git rev-list -n1 --first-parent --until="1 month ago" HEAD
```

That is: the first commit which was one month old.

Then a diff would be:

```
git diff --stat $(git rev-list -n1 --first-parent --until="1.month.ago" HEAD)
```