# How can I get the list of files changed in gerrit commits in a particular day?

Tags: git, gerrit

I wanted to know the files which got changed in my gerrit repo for a particular day.
Suppose If I run the command to fetch at 11:00 PM in the night It should fetch all the file names changed in a particular repo from 12:00 AM to 11:00 PM in the night.

I tried the below command but its fetching only last commit details :-

```
git log --name-only -n 1 HEAD~1..HEAD
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161609/how-can-i-get-the-diff-between-all-the-commits-that-occurred-between-two-dates-w

Answer (score 1):

You should use "git diff" instead of "git log":

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~1..HEAD
```