# Git diff of a file compared to a specific date

Tags: git

I'm doing this to get all changes of a certain file in a fresh clonend repo

```
git diff HEAD 'HEAD@{2020-01-01 ago}' -- file
```

but I get `warning: Log for 'HEAD' only goes back to` and not everything that changed.

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

Thanks for all the suggestions.
I got some good results from: `git diff $(git rev-list -n1 --until="timestamp" HEAD --) file`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the diff between all the commits that occurred between two dates with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161609/how-can-i-get-the-diff-between-all-the-commits-that-occurred-between-two-dates-w)

Answer (score 2):

[Git - gitrevisions Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emem)

> *@*
>
> *@* alone is a shortcut for `HEAD`.
>
> *[<refname>]@{}*, e.g. `master@{yesterday}`, `HEAD@{5 minutes ago}`
>
> A ref followed by the suffix *@* with a date specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. *{yesterday}*, *{1 month 2 weeks 3 days 1 hour 1 second ago}* or *{1979-02-26 18:30:00}*) specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time. This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (*$GIT_DIR/logs/*). Note that this looks up the state of your **local** ref at a given time; e.g., what was in your local *master* branch last week. If you want to look at commits made during certain times, see `--since` and `--until`.

Note that that documentation says about "local" ref.
Basically you can use this expression to refer to [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) of branches in local repository. Reflog is not shared with remote repository so it was not downloaded during clone.

So when you have fresh clone of repository you can use expression `HEAD@{date}` only if date refers after clone was made. You can use only dates when specific branch was updated on your local repository.
That is why you get this `warning: Log for 'HEAD' only goes back to`, since reflog of fresh clone has only one entry for `HEAD` (date of clone).

Basically you have to refer to required commit by other means (for example: use hash of the commit).

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR version of [Marek R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65792472/1256452) is that the `@{date}` syntax is unable to do what you want; don't try to use it for this purpose.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1161609/1256452) in [evolutionxbox's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792306/git-diff-of-a-file-compared-to-a-specific-date#comment116324342_65792306) goes to a rather old question whose answer contains most of what you need, though `git whatchanged` has been deprecated in favor of `git log --raw`.  The accepted answer has the key notion: `--since` (and `--until`, if you want it) is the way to do commit limiting by date.

You did however also specify *a certain file* (with the `-- pathspec` option).  Be aware that when using this with `git log`, Git will perform History Simplification, which will prune entire sub-graphs as it walks the Git commit graph.  Essentially, upon encountering a merge, Git will prune away any leg of the merge that *doesn't* match the then-current version of the file, unless that takes all legs of the merge.  That is, suppose we have:

```
...--o--o--◎
            \
             M--o--...
            /
...--o--o--●
```

where commits `◎` and `●` were merged to make commit `M`.  In commit `M`, there is a file named `file`.  This file appears in both `◎` and `●`.  The copy in `◎`, however, *exactly matches* the copy in `M`, while the copy in `●` is different.  The `git log` command, with the default history simplification turned on, will follow the *top* row of this diagram and *completely ignore* the *bottom* row.

This is because Git thinks you are looking for commits that resulted in the version of the file you see in commit `M`.  That is: how did we get *this* version of the file?  We got it because commit `M` *completely ignored* the branch that led up to the version that appears in commit `●`, so `git log` should likewise ignore that branch.

If this is what you want, that's good!  If not, be sure to use extra `git log` options to control or defeat the history simplification.  (The most straightforward option is `--full-history`, which does what it says.)